# life is wont -- What does "wont" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Assembly Language Step by Step—Programming with Linux, 3rd Edition by Jeff Duntemann (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470497025,miniSiteCd-BSG.html)

Example:

> Understanding that much about borrows gets you most of the way there; but,
>   **as life is wont**, you will frequently come across a subtraction similar to this...

In particular, it is not all that clear to me what **wont** really means here. In the dictionary, it says that the adjective **wont** is used only when spoken of a person and it means accustomed or in the habit of doing something. For example: *he was wont to arise at 5:30 every morning*. It doesn't really sound like the meaning given in the dictionary is going work here. Maybe there's something I don't understand. Please, be a good sport and help me figure this thing out.

Comment: It's a poor usage by the author, Duntemann. One could guess he's heard or read the word but doesn't have an adequate understanding of its meaning. The similar sentence *As life is accustomed to doing, you will frequently come across...* makes little sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **as life is wont**
>   *as life has repeated habits*

The hint is in the next line of your text

> you will **frequently come across** a subtraction similar to this...

you'll come across it often, since habits repeat in life.